# Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer

Tags: java, spring, rest, post

I am trying to do and https post to an site using spring rest template(It accepts post, but  doesn't accept JSON) with Spring MultiPart file upload.

Following error was received, when doing so,

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer.

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
formData.add("NUMBER", "ABC");
formData.add("ID", "123");
formData.add("FILE",file); // this is spring multipart file
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"); 
headers.set("Accept", "text/plain"); 
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(formData, headers);
RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate();

String result  = restTemplate.postForObject(uploadUri, requestEntity, String.class);
```

Comment: RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ObjectMapper newObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
newObjectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS,false);   MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter=new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
  restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter);
  restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
   
  return restTemplate;

Comment: Edit the question with additional info and delete the comment...

Answer (score 7):

I too faced the same problem and I was able to sort this out when I was using ByteArrayResource instead of FileSystem resource. I copied the byte contents of the multipart file into the httprequest entity using ByteArrayResource.

```
Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();
MultipartFile file = request.getFile(itr.next());
//Set the headers
................
formData .add("files", new ByteArrayResource(file.getBytes()));
```

You may refer this [link](https://techie-mixture.blogspot.com/2016/09/sending-multipart-requests-with-spring.html) to get more info

Answer (score -3):

Updating gradle plugin to version

```
id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
```

helped me